# What is ./lks.sh: Permission denied in Linux when running a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

When I run `lks.sh` file in my system it show permission denied:

```
./lks.sh  bash: ./lks.sh: Permission denied
```

What do I have to do to get this shell script to run?

This is my `.sh` file:

```
lokesh = "wait"
if[$lokesh == "wait"]
        echo "$lokesh"

else
        sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: I don't see the relevance for the tags `linux-device-driver` and `unixodbc`.

Comment: I would suggest you run your code through [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) after fixing the executable issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script has a few issues.

First the “Permission Denied” is most likely because your script does not have execute rights which would allow the script to actually run. So you need to `chmod` it like this:

```
chmod 755 lks.sh
```

And then you should be able to run it. FWIW, the `7` and `755` gives you—the owner—execute, read & write permissions while the `5` gives group members and others execute & read permissions. Feel free to change that to `744` so you are the only one who can edit that script but others—via `4`—can read it. Or even `700` so you are the only one who can ever do anything with that script.

But that said, your variable assignment for this seems off:

```
lokesh = "wait"
```

In my experience, there should be no spaces around the `=` like this:

```
lokesh="wait"
```

Next the spacing of this is syntactically incorrect:

```
if[$lokesh == "wait"]
```

It should be:

```
if [ $lokesh == "wait" ]
```

And finally your whole `if`/`else` syntax is incorrect; no `then` and no closing `fi`. So here is your final, cleaned up script:

```
lokesh="wait"
if [ $lokesh == "wait" ]; then
    echo "$lokesh"
else
    sudo shutdown -h now
fi
```

That said, the most immediate issue is the execute rights issue, but the other things will definitely choke your script as well.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't made your script executable:

```
chmod +x lks.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your shell script:

First as everyone has pointed out it requires executable bit to be turned on in order to run. You can do that by,

```
chmod a+x lks.sh
```

then running as you tried will work.

Now as [@Giacomo1968 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463891/117259) there are issues with your script:

First you should start all scripts with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).  This tells the operating system which interpreter to run for your script:

It should be the first line.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Now that we've picked the interpreter to be Bourn Shell the rest is how to program what you wish correctly, I will list the correct code and explain it line by line

```
#!/bin/sh

okesh="wait"

if [ $lokesh = "wait" ]; then
        echo "$lokesh"
else
        sudo shutdown -h now
fi
```

**White spaces matter in shell scripts**

1. `okesh="wait"`

   No spaces when specifying a shell variable, because the existance of `=` in the first token signifies to the shell that the statement is a variable declaration.

   Otherwise if you do it like this:

   ```
   okesh = "wait"
   ```

   The shell will attempt to look for a program called `okesh` and if it finds it, execute it and pass `=` and "wait" as two command line arguments to it.  Chances are you will get `okesh: command not found` error.
2. `if[$lokesh=="wait"]`

   you need a space after `if` and a space between `[` and `$lokesh` and another space between `$lockesh` and `=` and a space between `=` and `"wait"` and finally one between `"wait"` and `]`

   without all the spaces the shell thinks you are looking for a program named `if[$lokesh=="wait"]`

   with first space it realizes you are starting an `if` block (which requires a closing `fi` at the very end)

   `if` runs a program and looks at the return value, in this case that program happens to be `test` utility which has a synonym `[`.  In most *nix systems, including linux, test has a symbolic link `[` and when launched as '[' expects ']' as the last parameter.  In bash (bourne again shell) that's found on most linux systems '[' is also a built-in function and acts the same way.

See *test*(1) man page for details on how `[` works.

You are missing the mandatory `then` token, and the end `fi` token.

`if` is a built-in keyword. Use `help if` in bash to read how that works.